# A riddling revolution

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I've been in a bit of a riddling mood lately, so here is another one. I guess the question to answer is what is being described?

It could be argued that some specific knowledge is required to answer, but I think (hope) that it is general enough so as to be familiar to most.

> A revolution
>   The floodgates open
>   Rain's sucked in
>   The droughts broken
>
> A revolution
>   The floodgates close
>   The pressure rises
>   The pressure grows
>
> A revolution
>   A loud explosion
>   As fire from heaven
>   Sets things in motion
>
> A revolution
>   The gates ajar
>   A strong wind blows
>   Sending smoke afar
>
> A revolution
>   Begins anew
>   Back to step one
>   Through and through

Comment: This not only rhymes, but has an awesomely poetic feeling! Someone make this a song...

Comment: Could it be a train/steam engine? Revolution theme fits with the steam power and industrial revolution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This sounds like a description of

> a four-stroke internal combustion engine.

The revolution

> is of the crankshaft.

The rain

> is more likely petrol (or, if you prefer, gasoline).

The explosion

> is the ignition phase of the engine's operation.

In more detail:

```
A revolution
The floodgates open
Rain's sucked in
The droughts broken
```

> **Intake**! Valve opens, fuel is sucked into the chamber.

```
A revolution
The floodgates close
The pressure rises
The pressure grows
```

> **Compression**! The fuel-air mixture is compressed in preparation for what comes next.

```
A revolution
A loud explosion
As fire from heaven
Sets things in motion
```

> **Ignition**! The fuel is ignited and burns rapidly, producing copious gaseous products, which push the piston outward.

```
A revolution
The gates ajar
A strong wind blows
Sending smoke afar
```

> **Exhaust**! The waste products are expelled from the chamber, and ...

```
A revolution
Begins anew
Back to step one
Through and through
```

> ... we are ready to begin again.

Comment: Good job, beat me by a few seconds. Not quite the same answer, but the idea is the same.

Comment: This is the intended answer - well done! :) If you could perhaps explain/match the stanzas to the strokes for completeness that would be awesome

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the completion! Green tick for you.

Answer (score 8):

Possible solution?

> A car (or any motorised vehicle)

A revolution
The floodgates open
Rain's sucked in
The droughts broken

> A valve turning (revolving) in the engine letting fuel in.

A revolution
The floodgates close
The pressure rises
The pressure grows

> The valve turning again to close and allow pressure to build.

A revolution
A loud explosion
As fire from heaven
Sets things in motion

> The fuel ignites and the engine starts turning.

A revolution
The gates ajar
A strong wind blows
Sending smoke afar

> This one is a bit weakly connected, but maybe releasing the pedal to go, creating smoke in the process.

A revolution
Begins anew
Back to step one
Through and through

> The engine continues this cycle as long as the engine's running.

Comment: Great answer - I was looking for the specific component that Gareth gave, but your explanation of the first three verses was spot on. For the fourth verse, try matching it to r13(sbhegu fgebxr bs n pbzohfgvba ratvar)

Comment: Aha, I can see that now! I didn't know enough of how that component works. I definitely think Gareth deserves the tick.